# Catkinize GTSAM

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[GTSAM](https://bitbucket.org/gtborg/gtsam/overview) is a useful library for SLAM and I'd like to include it in my project (which I build with `catkin build my_project`). GTSAM is a cmake library, so how can I "catkinize" it? That is, I would like to edit the current [gtsam/CMakeLists.txt](https://bitbucket.org/gtborg/gtsam/src/cc25ece0551ba6ad1116046f5d4a19436d952d00/CMakeLists.txt?at=develop&fileviewer=file-view-default) such that when I run `catkin build my_project` GTSAM gets installed and I can include its headers within my_project source files.

I've been through [catkin docs](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html) and other questions ([e.g.](https://answers.ros.org/question/231131/using-catkin-to-install-libraries/)), but at this point I'm guessing blindly what lines to enter and where. Thanks in advance for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287240/catkinize-gtsam/) by [alavin89](https://answers.ros.org/users/33392/alavin89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2018-04-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The suggestions by @gvdhoorn are valid and a good approach, but given the constraint on installing GTSAM via `catkin_build` here is a solution:

Add to the top of the current gtsam/CMakeLists.txt add,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(gtsam)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS)

include_directories(
    gtsam
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

and at the bottom,

```
catkin_package()
install(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_NAME}
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
        PATTERN ".cpp" EXCLUDE
        PATTERN ".txt" EXCLUDE
        PATTERN ".in" EXCLUDE
        PATTERN ".dox" EXCLUDE
)
```

And the package.xml should be updated to reflect catkin:  `<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>`.

---

Originally posted by [alavin89](https://answers.ros.org/users/33392/alavin89/) with karma: 46 on 2018-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may not be the answer you were expecting, but in short: I wouldn't catkinise GTSAM. it's not needed.

Treat it as a *system dependency*, meaning that you'd treat it as just about any other "non-ROS" library. See wheher CMake already has a `FindGTSAM.cmake` (or whether someone else has written one) and add a `find_package(GTSAM REQUIRED)` to your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Then add `${GTSAM_LIBRARIES}` to your `target_link_libraries(..)` and `${GTSAM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}` to `include_directories(..)`.

That should do it.

---

Edit: see #q263158 for an earlier question about this (which links to [stackoverflow/44395859](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44395859)).

See [CognitiveRobotics/omnimapper/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/CognitiveRobotics/omnimapper/blob/a95b547b039553ffe0832fff0717c1c363dd2cec/CMakeLists.txt#L16-L21) for an example that shows the system dependency approach (but note that repository is a bit old).

If you really want/need to, you could take a look at [RoboStat/gtsam-in-ros](https://github.com/RoboStat/gtsam-in-ros).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alavin89](https://answers.ros.org/users/33392/alavin89/) on 2018-04-02**:
Thank you these are useful tips. I agree for most people it's probably best not to catkinize GTSAM, but my workspace builds beautifully because we catkinize everything. Another useful link: [gtsam_catkin middleman repo](https://github.com/Photogrammetry-Robotics-Bonn/gtsam_catkin).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-03**:
I don't really understand how "catkinise everything" is any better than `rosdep install --from-paths .. -i`, but if you're happy, then ok.